# Why does AngularJS not recognize that the value of my variable changed?

Tags: angularjs

I am using the following function in my app controller:

```
this.state = {
    net: false,
    netd: false,
    network: function (active) {
        if (active) {
            this.state.net = true;
            t = window.setTimeout(function () {
                this.state.netd = true;
            }.bind(this), 500);
        } else {
            window.clearTimeout(t);
            this.state.net = false;
            this.state.netd = false;
        }
    }.bind(this)
};
```

In my child controller I call it like this:

```
app.state.network(true);
```

Then after some time:

```
app.state.network(false);
```

In my child HTML I view the net and netd like this:

```
xx {{ app.state.net }} yy
xx {{ app.state.netd }} yy
```

The network function is called as expected and I can see `xx {{ app.state.net }} yy` change from false > true but `xx {{ app.state.netd }} yy` is always false even though the debugger shows it gets to be set as true here: `this.state.netd = true;`

Can anyone tell me why the state of netd does not seem to change in my browser ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the `window.setTimeout()` function, which changes the object without angularJS being aware of it. Use the [`$timeout` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout), which exists exactly to not have this problem, or manually call [`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope) every time you change a value as a result of an event that is not coming from angular.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `setTimeout()` with AngularJS ([generally speaking](https://coderwall.com/p/udpmtq)) as it executes "outside" of angular.

Instead of using `setTimeout`

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    this.state.netd = true;
}, 500);
```

Use the [angular `$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24timeout) service

```
$timeout(function() {
    this.state.netd = true;
}, 500);
```